# Scrapy append duplicate keys to mongodb list

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I have made a scraper with scrapy to extract data from google patents based on chemicals search. I search chemicals like this: `O1C(=CCCC1C)C` and I extract the publication number from the search results and store them in a mongodb database. The structure of the collection is this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6123733f10bd1504a29a9c75"), 
  "chemical" : "O=C(NCC1N(CC)CCC1)C2=C(O)C(=CC(Cl)=C2OC)CC",
  "publication_number" : ["EP3185946B1", "US10751533B2"]
}
```

The problem is this: If a chemical returns more than one page, in mongodb will store the same chemical two times but with different publication numbers. What I want to do is to check if the chemical exists in mongodb and if it will, I want to append the publication numbers in the already exist chemical record, otherwise if the chemical does not exist, I want to store it in the database

scraper.py

```
from pathlib import Path

import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

from pattents.items import PattentsItem

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

class PattentLinksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pattent_links'
    allowed_domains = ['patents.google.com']

    script = '''
        function main(splash, args)
            splash.private_mode_enabled = false
            assert(splash:go(args.url))
            while not splash:select('#resultsContainer') do
                splash:wait(3)
            end
            splash:wait(4)
            return splash:html()
        end
    '''

    def start_requests(self):
        
        with open(BASE_DIR.joinpath('spiders/urls.txt'), "rt") as f:
            start_urls = [url.strip().replace('=', '%3d') for url in f.readlines()]

        for url in start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(
                url='https://patents.google.com/?q=CL%3d' + url + '&page=0&num=100', 
                callback = self.parse,
                endpoint='execute',
                args={
                    'lua_source': self.script
                },
                meta={
                    'page_number': 0,
                    'chemical': url
                }
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        
        items = response.xpath('//search-result-item')

        if len(items) > 0:
            
            item = PattentsItem()
            
            pn = response.xpath('//span[@class="style-scope search-result-item"]/text()').getall()

            item['chemical'] = response.meta['chemical'].replace('%3d', '=')
            item['publication_number'] = pn

            yield item

            page_number = int(response.meta['page_number']) + 1

            yield SplashRequest(
                url= response.url.replace(f'&page={page_number - 1}', f'&page={page_number}'), 
                callback = self.parse,
                endpoint='execute',
                args={
                    'lua_source': self.script
                },
                meta={
                    'chemical': response.meta['chemical'],
                    'page_number': page_number
                }
            )
```

pipelines.py

```
import pymongo
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter

class PattentsPipeline(object):
    collection_name = 'items'

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(
            mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
            mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
        )

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.db[self.collection_name].insert_one(ItemAdapter(item).asdict())
        return item
```

Comment: You have a **lot** of clutter in your question. Isolate your issue down to just the problem you are having.

Comment: I want to check if a chemical exists on mongodb, and if so I want to append to the publication numbers list the new extracted publication numbers

Comment: So it seems like everything except the `process_item` function is irrelevant to the question, and from what you are describing, you probably want to upsert instead of insert.

Comment: I posted all this code for completion, probably I did not have to. Is it possible to give me an example with upsert, as I do not know this function.